# Chrome extension - This extension may have been corrupted

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I created an extension for Chrome. I need to allow the user to change a javascript file within the extension for various reasons.  When the whatever.js file is changed at C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\cidaekdakljdsijofjahinafcafmanb\6.0.5_0\whatever.js Chrome comes back with "This extension may have been corrupted." and I have to reinstall the extension.

How do I stop this?  How do I allow the changing of javascript file?  I'm just trying to set a variable.  Can I include a text file and change that instead? Under what circumstances can I get Chrome to stop doing this?

Can I add a user script?  whatever.user.js?  I read about that somewhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it by following proper development practices. If you are making the user edit the code to charge a variable, thats a huge coding issue.

Instead it should be changeable with a user interface, for example in the [extension options page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options). If you want full control of the option, download it from a server or read it from a web accesible extension resource json file. here is an example that reads from such file since you asked it in comments:

```
    var url = chrome.extension.getURL("options.json"); //in manifest under web_accessible_resources
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var options=null;
            try {
                options = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log("error: cant parse options.");

            }
            if (options) {
                //got it!
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.send();
```

this also simplifies a lot the user experience and possible user errors. just the fact that each OS stores and caches the code differently would be a nightmare to support.

and no, you cant bypass that chrome security measure meant to protect users from i.e. viruses modifying the extension source code.

Comment: So an IT administrator has to walk around to 1000 machines to make a small configuration change because it can only be done through the "options page".  There has to be a better way for larger scale deployments.

Comment: the options page was just an example based on the information the question provides. There are many other options available, like downloading settings from a server based on the user account, group membership, domain, licence, shared document or spreadsheet, firebase and so on. Question is too broad to address all possible ways to do it.

Comment: I'm just looking to change a setting via a file replacement somehow.

Comment: that's also possible if you include it as web accesible resource (json file for example) and read it from the javascript. Google a bit for similar samples. Doing that is weaker because it relies on all users having updated their extensions (which sometimes takes over a day after you publish an update).

Comment: What do you mean by OS cache? What cache?